# Is Tropicalization a Functor?

Tags: category-theory, tropical-geometry

Sorry if this is a basic or incoherent question, I can't seem to find any literature (written at my level of understanding of category theory) that addresses the "tropicalization" (unsure if this is even the right word) map from ordered abelian groups (generating semirings the same way that tropical arithmetic is created from the additive group of the reals).